# Show text when click on image hide text from previously image javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images and when I click on one of them a text appear. Then I want when clicking on another to show me the current text for that image.But now when click on another image, the previously text dissapear and have to click one more time on my image to display its text.It makes any sense?
My code is:

```js
  function showHide(a) {
   
   var div = document.getElementById("word");
   if (div.style.display == 'none') {
      div.style.display = '';
   $('#word').text(a);
   }
   else {
     div.style.display = 'none';
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="2">
<span id="word" style="display:none"></span>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
       <center><h1>House</h1></center>
      <audio id="sound9" src="audio/window.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound9').play();showHide('Window');"><img src="house/window.jpeg" id="window" alt="window" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img9"></span>
   <audio id="sound10" src="audio/table.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound10').play(); showHide('Table');"><img src="house/table.jpg" id="table" alt="table" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img10"></span>
   </br>
   <audio id="sound11" src="audio/roof.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound11').play();showHide('Roof');"><img src="house/roof.jpg" id="roof" alt="roof" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img11"> </span>
   <audio id="sound12" src="audio/floor.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound12').play();showHide('Floor'); "><img src="house/floor.jpg" id="floor" alt="floor" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img12"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you using Jquery, use it fully. Problem is after first click data is displayed and when you click on another image, your function checks if the `visibility is none`, which is `false`, and goes in `else` case and makes it hidden and in next click it checks again and this time goes in if condition and shows the text.

```js
function showHide(a) {
       var div = $('#word');
       div.text(a);
       
       if (!$(div).is(":visible")) {
          div.show();
       }
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="2">
<span id="word" style="display:none"></span>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
       <center><h1>House</h1></center>
      <audio id="sound9" src="audio/window.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound9').play();showHide('Window');"><img src="house/window.jpeg" id="window" alt="window" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img9"></span>
   <audio id="sound10" src="audio/table.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound10').play(); showHide('Table');"><img src="house/table.jpg" id="table" alt="table" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img10"></span>
   </br>
   <audio id="sound11" src="audio/roof.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound11').play();showHide('Roof');"><img src="house/roof.jpg" id="roof" alt="roof" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img11"> </span>
   <audio id="sound12" src="audio/floor.mp3" ></audio><a onclick="document.getElementById('sound12').play();showHide('Floor'); "><img src="house/floor.jpg" id="floor" alt="floor" width="220" height="160"></img></a>
   <span id="img12"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```